# I don't understand why I'm getting a segmentation fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
char* reverse(char s[]){

    int i, j;
    char t;

    for(i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--){
        t = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = t;
    }

return s;
}

int myPrefix (char s1 [], char s2 []) {

    int i;
    int comp = 0;

    for(i = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(s1[i] != s2[i])
            return comp;
        else
            comp++;
    }
    return comp;
}

int mySuffix (char s1 [], char s2 []) {

    return myPrefix(reverse(s1), reverse(s2));
}
```

I'm solving some codeboard challenges provided by my Uni but I'm stuck with this one. I'm supposed to make a function that compares 2 strings and returns the biggest suffix in common.

When I compile and run in codeboard I get a segmentation fault error, however the code runs perfectly in Clion.

Why is this happening?

Edit: Some of you commented that I didn't provide the code that calls the function. That is because I don't have access to it.

[This is the challenge in codeboard](https://codeboard.io/projects/14581)

Edit 2: I got it working. As some of you said I'm probably not allowed to modify the strings. Thank you for your help.

```
int mySuffix (char s1 [], char s2 []){

    int i = strlen(s1) - 1;
    int j = strlen(s2) - 1;
    int count = 0;

    for(; s1[i] == s2[j]; i--, j--){
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. How are you using these functions you show? Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please try to learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes, and how to locate when and where in your code they happen.

Comment: You haven't shown the code that calls this function (please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but I suspect you're calling it with string literals ?

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/UNYEkM

Comment: share the test cases for which you get the error!

Comment: Did the challenge mention that you were allowed to modify the strings passed in as parameter ? If not, you should probably assume that you are *not* allowed to do so.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The challenge doesn't mention anything about that, you might be correct. I will try again without modifying the strings. Thank you

Comment: you have a segmentation fault because you probably use a literal string as parameter : `reverse ("Abcdef");` wich is read only

Comment: Please note that the loop in the snippet of your last edit should also stop when i or j become negative.

Comment: It worked for me, just added main function and calling functions with string inputs.